# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile

Tags: python, django, file, binary

I am trying to upload a file to an another server. I am trying to do it like that:

```
 package = Package.objects.get(id=package_id)
 with open(package.logo_image.image, 'rb') as image_handle:
        image_data = bytes(image_handle.read())
        image = {
            'type': 'IMAGE',
            'data': image_data,
            'xsi_type': 'Image'
        }
        logo_image = media_service.upload(image)[0]
```

Field in a model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_file_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

After trying to run this code I get:

> with open(package.logo_image.image, 'rb') as image_handle:
>   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile

Converting to **str()** does not help.

Is is possoble to open this file i binary mode?
Thank you!

Comment: What is inside: `package.logo_image.image`? From the error you should provide the path to the image in the `open()` function.

Comment: The error does not match your code. It says you are doing `package.marketing_image.image.read()` not `open(package.logo_image.image)`. Which is it?

Comment: For pic I have smt like that(in django admin): Image: Currently: files/vARWl/CdJhO/gEwYBXesCr.jpg I doing it at with open(package... Can I open it binary? Or I should do it to another way?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. You need to show the *actual* code and the *actual* error, not two things that don't match.

Comment: I fixed it with correct pice of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to open the file at all. ImageField (and FileField) give you direct access to the underlying file object.

```
package = Package.objects.get(id=package_id)
image_data = bytes(package.logo_image.image.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open a relation of type `ImageField` for the purpose of reading the file as binary data.  For your example, this would use the syntax:

```
package.logo_image.image.open(mode='rb')
```

A useful case for this is if you want to use the `ImageField`'s image to POST data using the request module, for example:

```
file_list = [
    ('image[data]', (
        'image.jpg',
        package.logo_image.image.open(mode='rb'), 
        'image/jpg')
    ),
]
resp = requests.post(
        "http://example.com/image-ingester"
        files=file_list
 )
```

This is described under the `FileField` API documentation for Django ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField)).